# New wire to knob and tube switch

Tags: electrical, knob-and-tube

I’m running new lights in a basement, and is almost fully updated wiring. But once you get into the wall the original knob and tube. My problem is my parents want the new lights run off the switch. But where the switch runs into the box is knob and tube. And everything I’ve tried just trips the breaker. The box only has the hot running to it. Is this my problem?

Comment: Switches only need hot and switched hot.  Hot becomes switch hot on the second screw of the switch.  Breakers like to trip fast when hot and ground/neutral touches together.  You have a short somewhere in the circuit.

Comment: "everything I’ve tried just trips the breaker" leads me to believe that you're just trying random stuff, not getting it right, and have no idea what you're doing. Please call a friend who knows a little about electricity before you burn your parents house down.

Comment: If you want it coming of the same switch, just wire from an existing fitting (light)

Comment: "almost fully updated wiring" sounds almost legal to me.  I wouldn't do any of this unless the K&T is torn out.